# Any way to solve this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have not been able to solve the integral, any idea of how to do it?

> $$\int \frac{t}{\sqrt[t]{e}+1}\text dt$$

Comment: I don't think it has a closed form. Mathematica returns nothing.